# Yeild waitForSeconds(5.0) is not working

Tags: unity, 2d, unityscript

I am trying to call another function continuously from my Update() function. So, I have used yield WaitForSeconds(5.0); but, the it stops for the first 5 seconds and it does not stop the next time it goes inside the movement function. Basically, I want to stop for 5 seconds before every movement.

```
function Update () 
{
    movement();
}

function movement()
{   

    yield WaitForSeconds(5.0);
    //some blocks of code

}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, movement() is being called every single update resulting in repeatedly calls completing after the first five seconds - this is not what you want. You want to call movement once and have movement repeat itself. There might be a better pattern which if someone else can show would be great, but something like the following should work and get you pointed in the right direction -

**JavaScript:**

```
function Start () {
    StartCoroutine("movement");
}

function movement() {
    while (true) {
        yield WaitForSeconds(5.0);
        // some blocks of code
    }
}
```

**C#:**

```
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine("movement");
}

IEnumerator movement()
{
    while (true) {        
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(5.0f);        
        //some blocks of code
    }
}
```

Comment: Great. I am trying on this :)